# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS : Can't open snapstore gui

Tags: snap

I installed fresh ubuntu and installed snap store.

Now from application When I open snap store, it displays name in the in taskbaar n shows a loading cursor then closes down without any error.

Installing snap apps using terminals works fine though.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay here's how I solved the issue.

I installed snap-store from Ubuntu Software Centre and after that the issue mentioned in question.

**Solution**

1. Uninstall snap-store GUI from terminal (`snap remove snap-store`).
2. Install using `snap` command in terminal (`snap install snap-store`).
3. Open snap-store via terminal or apps (`snap-store`).

You may need to use sudo befare each command above to work.
**Done**

Comment: Had the same issue in 20.04, removing & installing again fixed here too.